# Can you bulk relink file references to a different directory in Maya?

Tags: python, maya

I am trying to open files with often 20+ file references pointing to an out of date directory. Is there a way (either built into maya on scriptable in python) that would save having to manually click "Browse" to find each file over and over again?

The new folder structure is the same I just need to bulk rename the start of the paths from  T:/ to Y:/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

here is a piece of code even if i didnt test it.

```
ref_node = cmds.ls('*RN*', type="reference", r=True)
for ref in ref_node:
    if cmds.referenceQuery(ref, isLoaded = True):
        ref_path =  cmds.referenceQuery (ref, f=True)
        new_path = ref_path.replace('T:/', 'Y:/')
        cmds.file(new_path, loadReference = ref)
```

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't seem to work unfortunately, does it only work if the reference is loaded in the old location first?

Comment: if cmds.referenceQuery(ref, isLoaded = True) check if it is loaded, you can remove the check if you want :)